# Can you restrict two characters based on their ASCII order in regex?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a string of 2 characters. Using regex (as a thought exercise), I want to accept it only if the first character has an ascii value bigger than that of the second character.

`ae` should not match because a is before e in the the ascii table.

`ea`, `za` and `aA` should match for the opposite reason

`f$` should match because $ is before letters in the ascii table.

It doesn't matter if `aa` or `a` matches or not, I'm only interested in the base case. Any flavor of regex is allowed.

Can it be done ? What if we restrict the problem to lowercase letters only ? What if we restrict it to `[abc]` only ? What if we invert the condition (accept when the characters are ordered from smallest to biggest) ? What if I want it to work for N characters instead of 2 ?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't have the slightest clue what could make this work :D. I have thought about a lot of options but I already know why each of them wouldn't work.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for such job.  The only solution, I think, is to code **all** the alternatives: `zy|zx|zw|...|ca|ba` good luck ;)

Comment: That's what I thought, but I want to see if I've missed something, possibly some obscure modifier (?WHATEVER), or a recursive check that removes letters one at a time reusing a previous regex, or something wizardy like that...

Comment: pretty sure that would be considered a META pattern you're trying to match, not a "_pattern_". Regular expressions are for pattern matching, and the flavors that go beyond that (like the ones with constructs to enable matching braces or whatever) are generally considered to be "irregular", however useful those features might be

Comment: Also there is already a feature on the subject (`[a-z]`), so maybe there are more

Answer (score 2):

I guess that'd be almost impossible **for me** to do it then, however [bobble-bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble) impressively solved the problem with:

```
^~*\}*\|*\{*z*y*x*w*v*u*t*s*r*q*p*o*n*m*l*k*j*i*h*g*f*e*d*c*b*a*`*_*\^*\]*\\*\[*Z*Y*X*W*V*U*T*S*R*Q*P*O*N*M*L*K*J*I*H*G*F*E*D*C*B*A*@*\?*\>*\=*\<*;*\:*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*\/*\.*\-*,*\+*\**\)*\(*'*&*%*\$*\#*"*\!*$(?!^)
```

#### [bobble bubble RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zYT1r8/2)

---

Maybe for `abc` only or some short sequences we would approach solving the problem with some expression similar to,

```
^(abc|ab|ac|bc|a|b|c)$
^(?:abc|ab|ac|bc|a|b|c)$
```

that might help you to see how you would go about it.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/byuKHI/1/)

---

You can simplify that to:

```
^(a?b?c?)$
^(?:a?b?c?)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/LDwLqH/1/)

but I'm not so sure about it.

---

> ### The number of chars you're trying to allow is irrelevant to the problem you are trying to solve:

because you can simply add an **independent statement**, if you will, for that, such as with:

```
(?!.{n})
```

where `n-1` would be the number of chars allowed, which in this case would be

```
(?!.{3})^(?:a?b?c?)$
(?!.{3})^(a?b?c?)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/zYT1r8/1/)

Comment: @toto are you referring to the fact that they're asking to "accept it only if the _first character_ has an ascii value bigger than that of the _first character_"?

Comment: or the fact that the examples seem to show opposite - probably that --- sorry, my pedantry got ahead of my reading...

Comment: @CodeJockey: And the string is 2 character long only.

Comment: Emma I Like your answer. [Here I did a little modification of your idea](https://regex101.com/r/zYT1r8/2) for longer words if @LogicalKip interested. Used [this php](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLKy2/SEMl09bQyMxaQSXTztgIROnqanIpKKQmZ@QrFBSlpscXluaXpGokZ4CUauqo66tr6qlrqXPZ2/3/DwA) to generate the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your update Emma, but I was just playing with your idea! :) OP asked for 2 characters only which better matches your solution with `(?!.{n})`. Thank you! however for include my comment:)

Answer (score 1):

A regex is not the best tool for the job.
But it's doable. A naive approach is to enumerate all the printable ascii characters and their corresponding lower range:

`\x21[ -\x20]|\x22[ -\x21]|\x23[ -\x22]|\x24[ -\x23]|\x25[ -\x24]|\x26[ -\x25]|\x27[ -\x26]|\x28[ -\x27]|\x29[ -\x28]|\x2a[ -\x29]|\x2b[ -\x2a]|\x2c[ -\x2b]|\x2d[ -\x2c]|\x2e[ -\x2d]|\x2f[ -\x2e]|\x30[ -\x2f]|\x31[ -\x30]|\x32[ -\x31]|\x33[ -\x32]|\x34[ -\x33]|\x35[ -\x34]|\x36[ -\x35]|\x37[ -\x36]|\x38[ -\x37]|\x39[ -\x38]|\x3a[ -\x39]|\x3b[ -\x3a]|\x3c[ -\x3b]|\x3d[ -\x3c]|\x3e[ -\x3d]|\x3f[ -\x3e]|\x40[ -\x3f]|\x41[ -\x40]|\x42[ -\x41]|\x43[ -\x42]|\x44[ -\x43]|\x45[ -\x44]|\x46[ -\x45]|\x47[ -\x46]|\x48[ -\x47]|\x49[ -\x48]|\x4a[ -\x49]|\x4b[ -\x4a]|\x4c[ -\x4b]|\x4d[ -\x4c]|\x4e[ -\x4d]|\x4f[ -\x4e]|\x50[ -\x4f]|\x51[ -\x50]|\x52[ -\x51]|\x53[ -\x52]|\x54[ -\x53]|\x55[ -\x54]|\x56[ -\x55]|\x57[ -\x56]|\x58[ -\x57]|\x59[ -\x58]|\x5a[ -\x59]|\x5b[ -\x5a]|\x5c[ -\x5b]|\x5d[ -\x5c]|\x5e[ -\x5d]|\x5f[ -\x5e]|\x60[ -\x5f]|\x61[ -\x60]|\x62[ -\x61]|\x63[ -\x62]|\x64[ -\x63]|\x65[ -\x64]|\x66[ -\x65]|\x67[ -\x66]|\x68[ -\x67]|\x69[ -\x68]|\x6a[ -\x69]|\x6b[ -\x6a]|\x6c[ -\x6b]|\x6d[ -\x6c]|\x6e[ -\x6d]|\x6f[ -\x6e]|\x70[ -\x6f]|\x71[ -\x70]|\x72[ -\x71]|\x73[ -\x72]|\x74[ -\x73]|\x75[ -\x74]|\x76[ -\x75]|\x77[ -\x76]|\x78[ -\x77]|\x79[ -\x78]|\x7a[ -\x79]|\x7b[ -\x7a]|\x7c[ -\x7b]|\x7d[ -\x7c]|\x7e[ -\x7d]|\x7f[ -\x7e]`

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/qhW4Zx/1)

---

A (better) alternative is to enumerate the ascii characters in reverse order and use the ^ and $ anchors to assert there is nothing else unmatched. This should work for any string length:

`` ^\x7f?\x7e?\x7d?\x7c?\x7b?z?y?x?w?v?u?t?s?r?q?p?o?n?m?l?k?j?i?h?g?f?e?d?c?b?a?`?\x5f?\x5e?\x5d?\x5c?\x5b?Z?Y?X?W?V?U?T?S?R?Q?P?O?N?M?L?K?J?I?H?G?F?E?D?C?B?A?@?\x3f?\x3e?\x3d?\x3c?\x3b?\x3a?9?8?7?6?5?4?3?2?1?0?\x2f?\x2e?\x2d?\x2c?\x2b?\x2a?\x29?\x28?\x27?\x26?\x25?\x24?\x23?\x22?\x21?\x20?$ ``

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/NiihLu/1)

You may replace `?` with `*` if you want to allow duplicate characters.

---

<sub>ps: some people can come up with absurdly long regexes when they aren't the right tool for the job: to parse [email](https://emailregex.com/), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233151/1033581) or the present question.</sub>